# How to have two functions invoked on submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#field-warning-message').hide();
    let empty_field_error = false;
    $('.verify-field').focusout(validateEmptyField);

    let resForm = $('.verify-form');
    let resFormBtn = $('#submit_reservation_form');
    let guestEmailInput = $('#guest-email');
    let emailErrorMessage = $('#email-error-message');
    let hostEmail = $('#guest-email').data('invalidity');

    function validateEmptyField() {
        $('.verify-field').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).val().length || null) {
                $('#field-warning-message').show();
                $('#field-warning-message').text("Please fill out required fields.");
                $(this).css('border-color', '#c65742');
                empty_field_error = true;
            } else {
                $('#field-warning-message').hide();
                $(this).css('border-color', '');
            }
        })
    }

    function validateHostEmail() {
        $('.validate-unique').each(function() {
            if (guestEmailInput.val() === hostEmail) {
                emailErrorMessage.text('Cannot use your email.');
                emailErrorMessage.addClass('red');
                empty_field_error = true;
            } else {
                emailErrorMessage.text('');
                emailErrorMessage.removeClass('red');
            }
        })
    }

    // resForm.on('submit', function () {
    resFormBtn.on('click', function () {
        empty_field_error = false;
        validateHostEmail();
        validateEmptyField();

        if (empty_field_error == false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="reservation_form" class="verify-form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required class="verify-field">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required class="verify-field">
    <input type="email" name="guest_email" id="guest-email" data-invalidity="data" placeholder="Email address" required class="verify-field validate-unique">
  </div>
  <div id="email-error-message"></div>
  <button id="submit_reservation_form" class="verify-form">
    Send Reservation
  </button>
</form>
```

I have a form that has input fields and an email input field. All fields on the form are validated by validateEmptyField() and one email input field is validated by validateHostEmail().
Validation works and both functions invoke only if click event appended to resFormBtn (submit button). However, the form submits and should not until validation is satisfied.

I need the form to validate both functions using the on submit event appended to the resForm (form class) and not submit until validation satisfied. I tried that and it did not work because only the validateEmptyField() is invoked for some reason and validateHostEmail() is not. Could be bubbling or trigger issue. Not sure.
Put form action to google.com in snippet. Type "data" in email field and see validation.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you add the relevant html as well for clarity.

Comment: @SangSuantak Just added html but formatting off for some reason.

Comment: I recommend listening to the ```"submit"``` event on the form instead of ```"click"``` event on button. Or you can try using ```event.preventDefault()``` and ```event.stopPropagation()```

Comment: I tried listening for submit event and it does not work. Here is a codepen, if you type "data" in email and hit submit the validation works only on click but not submit. https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/eYjmRxQ

Comment: @SangSuantak I updated to code snippet for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code and the problem was on returning false it needed event.stopImmediatePropagation();
Now it works perfect!
Shout out to @noiseymur for the tip.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $warningMessage = $('#field-warning-message');
    const $form = $('.verify-form');
    const $formBtn = $('#submit_reservation_form');
    const $guestEmailInput = $('#guest-email');
    const $emailErrorMessage = $('#email-error-message');
    const hostEmail = $guestEmailInput.data('invalidity');

    $warningMessage.hide();

    $('.verify-field').focusout(validateEmptyField);
    $form.on('click', validateForm);

    function validateEmptyField() {
        let hasEmptyField = false;
        $('.verify-field').each(function() {
            if (!$(this).val().length || null) {
                $warningMessage.show();
                $warningMessage.text("Please fill out required fields.");
                $(this).css('border-color', '#c65742');
                hasEmptyField = true;
            } else {
                $warningMessage.hide();
                $(this).css('border-color', '');
            }
        });
        return hasEmptyField;
    }

    function validateHostEmail() {
        let isHostEmail = false;
        $('.validate-unique').each(function() {
            if ($guestEmailInput.val() === hostEmail) {
                $emailErrorMessage.text('Cannot use your email.');
                $emailErrorMessage.addClass('red');
                $warningMessage.show();
                $warningMessage.text("Please fill out required fields.");
                $(this).css('border-color', '#c65742');
                isHostEmail = true;
            } else {
                $emailErrorMessage.text('');
                $emailErrorMessage.removeClass('red');
            }
        });
        return isHostEmail;
    }

    function validateForm(event) {
        if (validateHostEmail() || validateEmptyField()) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="http://www.google.com" id="reservation_form" class="verify-form">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required class="verify-field">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required class="verify-field">
    <input type="email" name="guest_email" id="guest-email" data-invalidity="data" placeholder="Email address" required class="verify-field validate-unique">
  </div>
  <div id="email-error-message"></div>
  <button id="submit_reservation_form" class="verify-form">
    Send Reservation
  </button>
</form>
```